# jQuery fetch particular word after entering white space

Tags: jquery

I have a sentence like this,

```
stackoverflow is the best place to get our doubts cleared.
```

Here, if I give a space in between the word `stackoverflow` and make it as `stack overflow`, the moment when I click on space bar I should get the word `stack`. I mean, where ever I press on space bar within my paragraph, I should get the word starts after the previous white space till the space I entered currently.

If it is just fetching the words from the end of paragraph, I can fetch them using `substring`. But, for this one I dont know how to move forward. Can anyone help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to post some code for help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code for this.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("#test").keypress(function (e) {
        var tBox = e.target;
        alert(tBox.value.substring(0, tBox.selectionStart).split(" ").pop());
    });
})
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/rkeG6/